# SignalR never start on iOS using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in my Xamarin Forms project.
It works perfectly when I'm using Android (device or simulator).
But using the same code on iOS, it hangs at `await hubConnection.StartAsync();`

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.
XAML hot reload is disabled.
I've tried adding the System.Memory and System.Buffers IncludeAssets None fix.

Here's the code

```
public async Task StartObserving()
{
    Uri signalRUri = new Uri("a-valid-uri-string-here");
    string jwt = await SecureStorage.GetAsync(SecureStorageKeys.IdToken);

    HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl(
            signalRUri,
            options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(jwt);
                options.WebSocketConfiguration = (clientWebSocketOptions) =>
                {
                    clientWebSocketOptions.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
                    {
                        return true;
                    };
                };
                options.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (httpMessageHandler) =>
                {
                    if (httpMessageHandler is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                    {
                        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, X509Certificate2 certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) =>
                        {
                            return true;
                        };
                    }

                    return httpMessageHandler;
                };
            })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
        .Build();

    hubConnection.On<string>(
        "Send",
        OnMessageReceivedFromSignalR);

    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
}
```

Here's the SignalR log

> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.453 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[40]
> Registering handler for client method 'Send'.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.464 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mtrce[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[42]
> Waiting on Connection Lock in StartAsyncInner (/_/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnection.cs:247).
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.472 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mtrce[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[80]
> The HubConnection is attempting to transition from the Disconnected state to the Connecting state.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.476 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[41]
> Starting HubConnection.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.486 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[1]
> Starting HttpConnection.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.503 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection[5]
> Skipping dispose, connection is already disposed.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.506 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mtrce[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[80]
> The HubConnection is attempting to transition from the Connecting state to the Disconnected state.
>
> 2022-03-23 13:21:01.506 MyApp.iOS[2581:54607]
> [40m[37mtrce[39m[22m[49m:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[20]
> Releasing Connection Lock in StartAsyncInner (/_/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnection.cs:280).

I'm getting the following Exception

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiationResponse
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiateProtocol.ParseResponse(System.ReadOnlySpan1)
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[TResult].Start[TStateMachine]
> (TStateMachine& stateMachine) [0x0002c] in
> /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:471
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.NegotiateAsync
> (System.Uri url, System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient,
> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003d] in
> :0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.GetNegotiationResponseAsync
> (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> [0x00011] in :0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport
> (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0017b] in
> :0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore
> (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00127] in
> :0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult () [0x0000c] in
> :0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync
> (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00091] in
> :0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync
> (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) [0x00114] in :0
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync
> (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) [0x001bf] in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore
> (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000a9] in
> <22c2b3ef3848439db8bf52b72cbcab20>:0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner
> (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001a3] in
> <22c2b3ef3848439db8bf52b72cbcab20>:0    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.ForceAsyncAwaiter.GetResult () [0x0000c] in
> <22c2b3ef3848439db8bf52b72cbcab20>:0    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync
> (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00091] in
> <22c2b3ef3848439db8bf52b72cbcab20>:0    at MyApp.StartObserving ()
> [0x0027b] in C:\Dev\MobileApp\MyApp\MyApp\Services\CacheService.cs:279

Comment: It looks like you're missing logs. Where are the Info and Error level logs?

Comment: There are no other logs as far as I know? As you can see I set the minimum level to trace, it's all I can see in the Output of Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, then that means you're getting an early exception from HubConnection.StartAsync from the initial negotiate request. If you put a try catch around StartAsync you can observe it.

Comment: have you verified connectivity between your device and the hub server?

Comment: @Jason I have, the server with the signalr endpoint and the rest endpoint is the same. the rest calls resolve correctly.

Comment: @Brennan I've updated my question with the Exception I'm getting

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/20805#issuecomment-791440473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had only half of the solution implemented.

What fixed it for me was adding this to **BOTH** the common AND iOS projects.
Not only the common project.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Buffers">
  <Version>4.5.1</Version>
  <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="System.Memory">
  <Version>4.5.4</Version>
  <IncludeAssets>none</IncludeAssets>      
</PackageReference>
```